# Preventing multiple instances of a GTK application

Tags: c, gtk

I have written a GTK application in C on my Linux system.
At present, I can open or start multiple instances of my application.
How can I modify the code so that only one instance at a maximum can run at a time?

I know that there are many ways to achieve this.
One is to use an X selection; another is to use a pipe/lock file; yet another one is to use D-Bus.

I want to use D-Bus, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `GtkApplication`, which provides you with single-instance support by default.

if you cannot use `GtkApplication` then you can use `libunique` (which is deprecated by `GtkApplication` but works fine with both GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3.x): https://wiki.gnome.org/LibUnique

alternatively, you can implement the same system used by both `GtkApplication` and `libunique`, which is based on DBus: you should acquire a well-known name for your application in the first instance, and if something is already holding that well-known name, meaning that there already is an instance running, then exit from your application.

Answer (score 4):

[GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html) is what you want. Basically, all you need to do is pass an unique string to [gtk_application_new()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#gtk-application-new). The page of its base class, [GApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html), explains the details.

Comment: My app need to be ported to GtkApplication. Now I don't have time for this, is to big. Anyway thanks